# What is the chemical equation for wine fermentation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, food-chemistry

I am researching about the impact of sugar on wine fermentation, so I am looking for the equation of that reaction. However, there are a few different versions from different sources, so I was wondering which one is the right one to use and what does each equation represent?

\begin{multline}
\ce{Glucose + 2 NAD+ + 2 Pi + 2 ADP ->}\\
 \ce{2 pyruvate + 2 NADH + 2 ATP + 2 H+ + 2 H2O + heat}\tag{1}
\end{multline}
\begin{gather}
\ce{C6H12O6 -> 2CH3CH2OH + 2CO2 + ATP}\tag2\\
\ce{C6H12O6 -> 2C2H5OH + 2CO2}\tag3
\end{gather}

Answer (score 5):

Generally there are two types of fermentation in biochemical processes:

- homolactic fermentation
- alcoholic fermentation

Both these processes occur under anaerobic conditions to replenish NAD+ 
by the reduction of pyruvate in an extension of the glycolytic pathway.

1. The overall reaction in muscles is:
   $$\ce{Glucose + 2ADP + 2Pi -> 2 lactate + 2ATP + 2H2O + 2H^+}$$
2. For alcoholic fermentation:

   Glucose is first converted to pyruvate by glycolysis, and the pyruvate is converted to ethanol and $\ce{CO2}$ in a two step process:

   [image]
   Note: For the second one we just started with pyruvate (to show mechanism and enzymes involved)Otherwise, for alcoholic fermentation, the net reaction is:

   $$\ce{Glucose + 2ADP +2Pi + 2H+ -> 2CO2 + 2C2H5OH +2ATP +2H2O}$$

*Both homolactic and alcoholic fermentation have the same function: the anaerobic regeneration of NAD+ for continued glycolysis. Their main difference is in their metabolic products*

Having said that lets go back to experimental wine fermentation, it is essentially alcoholic fermentation (2).

Enzymes in yeast (zymase a mixture of enzymes) and  cozymase  a mixture of cofactors-coenzymes such as NAD+ , ATP, and ADP, as well as metal ions) help carry out the fermentation reactions.

Comment: So pyruvate converts to acetaldehyde while giving out CO2, then converts to ethanol, while NADH converts to NAD+? What would be the equation for that reaction? Is this process within the Glucose⟶2CO2+2C2H5OH process?

Comment: @Izy instead I have put net equations (starting all the way from glycolysis) but I wanted to emphasize the conversion of pyruvate to ethanol and CO2 in alcoholic fermentation